# how can i get apk file path from java application?

Tags: android

how can i get apk file path from my java application?
I have apk file in android device and i want to find the path for same apk using java application.Is it possible to get using ADB command?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By default android has an app called dev tools.
Launch the dev tools . so It is as follows..

```
Dev Tools --> Package Browser --> Click on the app
```

Thats all u will get path of apk

or Install apk on the emulator.And Android Emulator has an app called dev tools.

and do in the same manner as mentioned above ..

Answer (score 0):

Try the following from the adb shell

$ adb shell pm list packages -f